# When is Outlook autodiscover for O365 used, other than initial mailbox setup?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

What circumstances is autodiscover used with Outlook with Office 365, other than the initial setup of a user's mailbox?

Comment: Short answer: Nothing other than initial set up.

Comment: See [Autodiscover in Outlook: What it is and how it works](https://techgenix.com/autodiscover-in-outlook/) for full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autodiscover is an Exchange service that, among other things,
automatically configures account settings in Outlook.

Autodiscover is a feature in Microsoft Exchange, to set up apps on a phone
or a computer using just an employee’s email address and password.
It’s meant to make it easier to set up an email or calendar app,
for example, by offloading the hard work to the server rather than
configuring the app by hand.

It's only used when connecting to the Exchange server. After Outlook is
fully connected, it's not required and has no other role.

References :

- [Autodiscover in Outlook: What it is and how it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/autodiscover?source=recommendations&view=exchserver-2019)
- [Autodiscover flow in an Office 365 environment](https://o365info.com/autodiscover-flow-in-an-office-365-environment-part-1-of-3-part-29-of-36/)

Answer (score 1):

The Autodiscover is designed for Exchange Server to minimizes user configuration and deployment steps by providing clients access to Exchange features. It is not specifically designed for Outlook.

For example, Autodiscover can be used for network protocol. For Exchange Web Services (EWS) clients, Autodiscover is typically used to find the EWS endpoint URL. However, Autodiscover can also provide information to configure clients that use other protocols. Autodiscover works for client applications that are inside or outside firewalls and in resource forest and multiple forest scenarios.

About more information about Autodiscover ,you can info this Microsoft Document:[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/autodiscover?view=exchserver-2019)